# Suppose that G is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ where n≥2.

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that G is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ where n≥2.

**(a) Give the definition of the permutation module W of G over the complex numbers.**

*Let G be a subgroup of $S_n$ and let V be a vector space with basis {$v_1,v_2,…v_n$}. Define an action of G on V by setting $g.v_i=v_{g(i)}$ and extending linearly. Then V is an FG module called a permutation module.*

**(b)Write down a formula for the character of W in terms of the number of fixed points by each g in G.**

*For g in $S_n$, let $fix(g)$ be the number of fixed points by g and then $fix(g)$ is a character of G.*

**(c)Find a 1 dimensional submodule X of W and hence show that there exists a CG module U whose character is given by $\chi_u(g)$=$fix(g)-1$ for all g in G.**

I am not too sure where to start with this part. 
Thanks

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: sorry it is part (c)

Comment: A hint I can give is to think about taking a sum over all elements of $G$. I'll elaborate more if you remain stuck.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: A 1-dimensional submodule is pretty small; it has to be cyclic; generated by a single vector. If you take a random vector $\sum a_i v_i$ and apply a permutation $g$ to it, then it seems unlikely that you'd get a multiple of $\sum a_i v_i$ because it reorders the $a_i$. How could you choose the initial $a_i$ so that re-ordering them doesn't matter?

Comment: @JackSchmidt Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).